# how to remove all html characters in snowflake, dont want to include all html special characters in query (no hardcoding)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, htmlcleaner

Want to remove below kind of characters from string..pl help
'
&

Comment: Added more explanation to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this one to remove any HTML special characters:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE( 'abc&amp;def&sup3;&raquo;ghi', '&[^&]+;', '!'  );
```

Explanation:

REGEXP_REPLACE uses regular expression to search and replace. I search for "&[^&]+;" and replace it with "!" for demonstration. You can of course use '' to remove them. More info about the function:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_replace.html

About the regular expression string:

- & is the & character of a HTML special character
- [^&] means any character except &. Tthis prevents to REGEXP to replace all characters between the first '&' char and last ';'. It will stop when it see second '&'
- + means match 1 or more of preceding token (any character except &)
- ; is the last character of a HTML special character

Comment: Thank you..it is working for me..could you pls let me know what is the logic behind this regex. Thanks

Comment: also it is removing & part of string

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION UDF_StripHTML(str varchar)
  returns varchar
  language javascript
  strict
  as 
  'var HTMLParsedText=""
   var resultSet =  STR.split(''>'')
   var resultSetLength =resultSet.length
   var counter=0
   while(resultSetLength>0)
   {
      if(resultSet[counter].indexOf(''<'')>0)
      {    
        var value = resultSet[counter]
        value=value.substring(0, resultSet[counter].indexOf(''<''))
        if (resultSet[counter].indexOf(''&'')>=0 && resultSet[counter].indexOf('';'')>=0) 
        {
            value=value.replace(value.substring(resultSet[counter].indexOf(''&''), resultSet[counter].indexOf('';'')+1),'''')
        }
      }
        if (value)
        {
          value = value.trim();
          if(HTMLParsedText === "")
          {
              HTMLParsedText = value
          }
          else
          {
            if (value) {
              HTMLParsedText = HTMLParsedText + '' '' + value
            }
          }
          value=''''
        }
        counter= counter+1
      resultSetLength=resultSetLength-1
   }
    return HTMLParsedText';
  
to call this UDF :

Select UDF_StripHTML(text)
```